# Zoom issue with responsive mobile website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The mobile version of my website zoomes way too much in. For some reason I haven´t this issue when calling the website with chrome and leaving out "initial-scale=1". There is definetly something wrong cause the result of Google responsive check is: Content is larger than the display.

I have already tried any kind of combination with viewport, like min-scale, max-scale, shrink-to-fit=no or setting a fixed witdh size for content.

HTML

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <we:css id="4" /><we:css id="5" />
    <we:content name="head" />      
</head>
<body>
    <a name="top"></a>
    <div id="wrap-outside"><div id="wrap-inside">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="header-left"><we:img ...</div>
            <div id="header-right">
                <div id="office"><we:a id="6"><we:img name="officetitle" id="18" showcontrol="false" border="0" /></we:a></div>
                <div id="navibar"><div id="navibar-content"><we:include id="5" type="template" /></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="left" >
                <we:include id="4" type="template" />
                <div id="links-call"><a href="tel:040 27163906"><img src="/images/picture1.png"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="right"><we:content /></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="footer"><p><we:a id="15">Impressum</we:a></p></div>
        </div>
        </div></div>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

#text{
    font-size:190%;
}

#header-right{
    width:100%;
}

#header-left{
    display:none;
}

#navbar{
position: relative;
width:100%;
}

#content-left{
display:none;
}
```

... AND SO ON

Comment: Can you post a piece of HTML? Maybe your `font-size: 190%` is the problem because your `meta` looks good

Comment: Changing the font size unfortunately didn´t work

Comment: Please [edit] your *question* to include the HTML there, not in an answer.